# Конфигурирование Https в JAX-RS.

Tags: java, http, https, jax-rs

Пишу веб-приложение с использованием JAX-RS (RESTeasy на WildFly). Успешно настроил защищённое HTTPS соединение, но возник вопрос: можно ли каким-либо способом конфигурировать то, какие методы должны использовать только защищённое соединение, а какие могут использовать обычный HTTP?

Пока что мне удалось добиться только того, чтобы использовать только защищённое соединение на всём сервере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спецификация JAX-RS дает вам способ аннотациями превратить POJO в веб-сервис, но мало заботится о конкретном транспорте. Протоколы HTTP и HTTPS находятся в ведении веб-сервера, который будет направлять запросы на ваши веб-сервисы.

Раз у вас идет работа с HTTP и HTTPS, очевидно у вас на сервере сконфигурировано два listener-а, и оба обслуживают одни и те же веб-сервисы. В свете этого, я бы предложил завести свою аннотацию, например такую:

```
@NameBinding
public @interface HttpsOnly {}
```

и написать фильтр, который будет проверять схему запрашиваемого URL-а, вроде такого.

```
@HttpsOnly
public class HttpsOnyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        if (!requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().getScheme().equals("https")) {
            Response response = ... ; // /* какой-то Response на ваше усмотрение*/
            requestContext.abortWith(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь можно вешать аннотацию куда попало:

```
@Path("foo")
public class MyService {
    @GET
    public Foo getFoo() {
    }

    @POST
    @HttpsOnly
    public Foo createFoo(Foo foo) {
    }
}
```

---

PS. Конкретно с WildFly не знаком, но этот способ будет работать с любой реализацией спеки JAX-RS 2.0

Comment: Во второй раз уже мне помогаете по этой теме. Весьма благодарен. Что-то такое я и предполагал, но не  мой фильтр отказывался корректно работать (видимо, использовал кое-что другое). Благодарю.